# how can I get file name and path in java?

Tags: java, file, directory, filepath

I have a zip file in a directory which his name dynamicaly changes.
when I click on a button I should be able to get full path of this file plus the name as follow: `U:\home\ash\dfi\dfiZipedFile\dfi.zip`

```
public static String getFileFullName(BcfiDownloadPanel bcfiDownloadPanel) {
    File dir = new File("U:\\home\\ash\\dfi\\dfiZipedFile");

    String[] filesList = dir.list();
    if (filesList == null) {
        // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++) {
            // Get filename of file or directory
            String filename = filesList[i];
        }
    }
    String fileFullName = filesList[0];

    return fileFullName;
}
```

Comment: Is there only ever one ZIP in that directory?  How is it you know the directory, but not the file name?  How does that code compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static String getFirstZipFilename(File dir) {        
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        if (file.isFile() && filePath.endsWith(".zip")) {
            return filePath;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

- Works with any directory (try to make your utility methods generic...)
- Returns as soon as a valid file has been found (no useless tests)
- Returns null if nothing was found, so you can know it and display warning messages

Comment: First, you should never use assertions to check preconditions in a public API. Second, the assertion is superfluous because the dir reference is immediately derefenced by calling dir.listFiles().

Comment: True for the second point. About the first one, it depends if the class is meant to be used in a public library or not. However, in doubts, you're right, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
String ret = null;

File dir = new File("U:/home/ash/dfi/dfiZipedFile");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
{
  if (!file.isDirectory())
  {
    ret = file.getPath();
    break;
  }
}

return ret;
```

returns the full path of the first file in the directory.

Comment: this should be corrected as somebody mentioned above
`File dir = new File("U:\\home\\ash\\dfi\\dfiZipedFile");`

Comment: What about if there is more file with other extinction.
How can i denied other extension?

Comment: You can use a FilenameFilter in listFiles or test the filePath with filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")

Comment: I think File("U:/home/ash/dfi/dfiZipedFile") works fine. Whats the problem with that. I don't know if File("U:\\home\\ash\\dfi\\dfiZipedFile") works on Unix machines.

Answer (score 1):

I would be stunned if this code would work.

you should replace the `\` with `\\` in the filename.

Comment: This should be a comment on the original question.

Comment: @james.garriss The objective is to help him. My answer will make his code compile so it is "part" of the answer and not a pure comment. So both work, either a comment or an answer. I honestly went for an answer because upvoted comments don't give you points ..